# Is erubis still faster than erb?

Tags: ruby, erb, erubis

I'm choosing a templating system for a gem, so I was thinking to use Erubis which [it seems to be faster than ERB](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/), but [the last released version is from 2011](https://rubygems.org/gems/erubis/versions).
As ERB is integrated into the ruby stdlib, I guess their performance has been improved these last three years but I don't know if has been improved enought to surpass to Erubis.

Comment: You can find answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620228/ruby-2-1-with-erubis-template-engine/27690911